# ДельтАплан, но дельтОвидный. Почему?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, однокоренные-слова, сложные-слова

1. *Дельт**а**план, дельт**а**дром, дельт**а**лёт*.
2. *Дельт**о**видный* (фикус, тополь), *дельт**о**видная* (мышца, связка), *дельт**о**образный* (двигатель, барьер).

Почему в сложных словах в первой группе правильно **А**, а во второй — **О**?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Я не нашла, что думает о сём феномене наука, но закономерность некоторая наблюдается.

Там, где мы имеем дело со сложением основ - *дельтадром/дельтаклуб/дельтаплан,* принято писать А (а проблема с *дельта* другая - в словарном порядке заучивать слитное и черездефисное написание - дельта-импульс, к примеру),

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а там, где происходит сложение корня с "недословом" (называемым "второй частью сложных слов"), договорились считать греческую букву дельта склоняемой, то есть конечное А - окончание, которое следует заменить привычной нам соединительной гласной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Логики никакой, и искать ея не надоть.

---

Мне очень нравится сайт **[Издательство «ЛИЦЕЙ»](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/651-28_slozhnye_slova_soedinitelnye_glasnye_i_suffiksy_v_slozhnyh_slovah_pravopisanie_glasnyh_v_slozhnyh_slovah.html)**.

...В ряде случаев конечная гласная первой части сложного слова (обычно это иноязычный элемент) входит в состав корня.

---

Правописание соединительных гласных подчиняется следующему правилу:
*-о-* пишется после твёрдых согласных (кроме *ж, ш, ц*), *-е-* пишется после мягких согласных и *ж, ш, ц.*

Но есть и другой ряд, о котором не спрашивают "почему", а заучивают или живут в обнимку со словарём:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Постижимо ли сие умом? Русь, куда ж несёшься ты? дай ответ. Не даёт ответа. ©

Лирика a parte: не, ну а почему "дай ответ" со строчной-то?! О_о

Answer (score 2):

Слово "дельт**а**план" было заимствовано из фр. *delt**a**plane*, поэтому оно пишется через букву "а" (это не мешает ему быть сложным словом с первой частью *дельт**а**-*).

Слова "дельтадром" (греч. *δέλτα* (*дельта-*) + *δρόμος* (*-дром*); скорее всего, собственно русское сложение основ по аналогии со словами "аэродром", "гипподром" и т. п.) и "дельталёт" (греч. *δέλτα* (*дельта-*) + *лететь* по аналогии со словами "самолёт", "вертолёт" и т. п.) пишутся через букву "а", потому что представляют собой собственно русские сложения основ, первая из которых — *дельт**а*** (греч. *δέλτ**α***).
По такому же принципу через "а" пишутся слова "дельтапланеризм", "дельтаклуб".

В русском языке есть слово "дельта", обозначающее название четвертой буквы греческого алфавита. Оно склоняется: нет дельт**ы**, любуюсь дельт**ой** — следовательно, его основа — *дельт*.
Слова "дельтовидный" и "дельтообразный" были образованы сложением основ с соединительной гласной *о* (первая основа в обоих случаях — *дель**т***, а не *дельта*!), поэтому и пишутся они через букву "о".